# How to specify correlations of two slopes with random intercept, without adding correlation between the random slopes (lme4)?

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, covariance-matrix

I am trying to specify a model in R's `lme4` package in which I have 2 correlations between random intercept and random slopes, but the random slopes are not allowed to correlate.

```
lmer (Y ~ A + B + (1+A+B|Subject), data=mydata)
```

is bad because it models correlation between the random slopes for A and B. Whereas:

```
lmer (Y ~ A + B + (1+A|Subject) + (1+B|Subject), data=mydata)
```

is bad because the random intercept for Subject gets introduced into the model twice. Is there a third way, perhaps more hack-ish?

**UPDATE:** This has been answered by @BenBolker on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401176.

Comment: I don't think this is do-able without some hacking: if it gets re-posted on StackOverflow, I can try to answer.  Basically, you have to follow the steps in `?modular` to set up the structures, then write a wrapper function that fills in zeros in the appropriate places.

Comment: I re-posted it on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35399127/1797369), thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think this was off-topic here. We have an identical question that is still open (but no satisfactory answer): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62033 and of course hundreds of very similar questions on how to achieve this or that with lmer (or other package).