# Uncorrelated random slopes in lme4?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model

I am trying to fit a linear mixed effects model with a response variable (y) and two categorical predictors (x1 and x2). Part of the reproducible example for this is below,

```
## Loading packages

library(afex)
library(lme4)

## Setting up data frame

set.seed(666)

id <- factor(1:10)
a <- factor(rep(c("a1","a2"),each=5000/2))
b <- factor(rep(c("b1","b2"),each=5000/2))
y <- rnorm(5000,10,3)
df <- data.frame(id=id,
                 x1=sample(a),
                 x2=sample(b),
                 y=y)
```

The question I have is pertaining to the random effects structure. Now, I know I can fit a maximal random effects structure (intercept, effect of x1, effect of x2, interaction between x1 and x2 varying across different ids as well as correlations between all the random effects) using the `lmer` function from the lme4 package (fit_1a) or `mixed` function from afex package (fit_2a) as below,

```
## Full random effect structure using lme4

fit_1a <- lmer(y ~ x1 * x2
                  + (x1*x2|id),
                  data = df)

## Full random effect structure using mixed

fit_2a <- mixed(y ~ x1 * x2
                + (x1*x2|id),
               data = df)
```

I also realise that I can specify my random effects structure to be uncorrelated via the `||` notation in the `mixed` function (fit_2b), as below,

```
## Fitting model without correlations using afex::mixed

fit_2b <- mixed(y ~ x1 * x2
                  + (x1*x2||id),
                  expand_re = TRUE,
                  data = df)
```

This ensures no correlations between *any* of the random effects (none between the random intercept and the random slopes as well as none between the various random slopes itself).

Now, I am trying to do the above using the `lmer` function and while `(0 + x1 * x2|id) + (1|id)` removes correlations between the random intercept and random slopes, it doesn't remove the correlations between the random slopes itself. I tried the model below (fit_1b) but still get values for correlations between the random slopes.

```
fit_1b <- lmer(y ~ x1 * x2
               + (0 + x1:x2|id)
               + (0 + x1|id)
               + (0 + x2|id)
               + (1|id),
               data = df)
```

I would appreciate any help or insight, thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to specify uncorrelated random slopes in lmer() syntax?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62033/how-to-specify-uncorrelated-random-slopes-in-lmer-syntax)

Comment: Thanks Robert :) While that link itself doesn't answer it, a link in the comment section of that link does provide an answer,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35401176/8816091

Comment: Yes, I noticed that too. It's a rather tricky solution,  but it does seem to work. However, I would advise caution in forcing correlations to be zero. Things in the natural world tend not to be that way, and it may be an unrealistic constraint on the model.

Comment: Indeed. I am trying to fit the maximal random effects structure as advised here http://singmann.org/download/publications/singmann_kellen-introduction-mixed-models.pdf but am running into trouble getting the model to converge. Hence, was looking at simplifying it. Given that the correlations amongst random slopes take up the most number of random effect parameters, I was looking to remove them.